# How can I know my memory's "actual frequency" in ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, ram, overclocking, dmidecode

I bought some memory stick which is ovcerclockable. The default frequency is 2.4GHz, the frequency can be configured up to 3.6GHz. And I confiured frequency and the voltage in BIOS, set the frequency to 3.6GHz. Then I ran the memtester86 8.1, to test if overclocking is stable, and it passed all test with no error on 3.6 GHz. Finally, I entery the OS(my OS version is 18.04),and execue `sudo dmidecode --type 17  | grep -i speed`, it shows like below:

```bsh
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Clock Speed: 3600 MT/s
```

I wonder which is the "actual" frequency of my memory? Did I overclocking success?
And I tried another command, `sudo lshw -short -C memory`, and it shows this:

```bsh
H/W path         Device        Class          Description
=========================================================
/0/0                           memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/1b                          memory         System Memory
/0/1b/0                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/1b/1                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/1b/2                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/1b/3                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/20                          memory         System Memory
/0/20/0                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/20/1                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/20/2                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/20/3                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/33                          memory         768KiB L1 cache
/0/34                          memory         12MiB L2 cache
/0/35                          memory         19MiB L3 cache
/0/1                           memory
/0/3                           memory
/0/100/1f.2                    memory         Memory controller
```

It just let me more confusing. Dose overclocking independent with OS? Or I should add some payload to let memory speed up? Can you give me some advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only component in your computer that knows about the overclocking is BIOS. `dmidecode` retrieves its data from BIOS, which tells you that the DIMMs have a nominal speed of 2400 MT/s but are configured to run at 3600 MT/s.

`lshw` prints the data that the components report themselves. Since the DIMMs don't know they are overclocked, they report their nominal speed.

Therefore, I'd say the DIMMs are overclocked.

There is a Q&A over at serverfault regarding [benchmarking RAM](https://serverfault.com/q/372020). I'm not sure whether the answers provide reliable results, though.

Comment: This is an easy way.  That link you provided is too complicated...
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32517/how-can-i-observe-memory-bandwidth/597660#597660